# SMTP Open Relay using AWS SES

Tags: amazon-web-services, smtp

Good day,

As an ISP, We currently have an open SMTP relay that we allow access from our customer's IP ranges. This is a very low volume email platform.

We are considering to move this service to the AWS using the Simple Email Service (SES) platform for its attractive prices. However it doesn't seem to support non-authenticated relay filtered by IP addresses range.

Anyone can confirm if this is achievable or you mandatory need SMTP auth?

Comment: I don't think it even makes sense. The whole point of an ISP running an SMTP relay is to filter out spam from its customers and provide them with normal email service. SES is not designed for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I’m pretty sure it’s *not possible* to send through SES based on IP whitelisting. Amazon needs to do the authentication to be able to *bill* for the messages sent by different AWS Accounts.

If you want to use SES for your outbound SMTP traffic for your customers you can spin up a small EC2 instance (e.g. t3.micro) with e.g. *Postfix* and let the customers send through that. You can do IP-based whitelisting, some basic spam and antivirus checks, etc.

From there you can despatch the emails to SES for delivery.

Hope that helps :)